# How can two Classes in C++ notice each other?

Tags: c++

For example a little Computergame with three Classes Player, Bot and Game

Player has a Method that checks if the Player collide with a bot

```
// Player.h
#include Game.h   
#include Bot.h

class Player {
    private:
    bool collision(Game g)  {

       for (Bot bot: g.bots)
       ...
     }

};
```

The Bot.h (kept simple, of cause it has some other attributes like actual position and so far)

```
// Bot.h


class Bot {
    public:
    Bot()
};
```

The Gameclass handles the Gameloop and the List of Bots

```
//Game.h
#include Bot.h    
#include Player.h

class Game {

public:
Player player:
std::vector<Bot> bots
void loop() { player.collision() }

};
```

So here we have the problem that Game.h includes Player.h and the other way around.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why does player.h include game.h? In the code you have posted there is no reason. If there is a good reason for player.h to include game.h then we need to know what it is before we can give a solution.

Comment: john, you're right, thanks. I've corrected it. The for-loop should be in player-class and not in game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the other answers here are certainly technically correct, whenever I come across a situation like this I see it as pointing out a potential flaw in my design. What you have is **cyclic dependencies**, like so:

[image]

This isn't just a problem for your implementation, it means that there is too much [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) between classes, or, conversely, too little information hiding. This means that you can't design the `Player` independently of the `Game`, for example.

So if possible, I'd prefer a situation like this, where the `Game`, as the controller delegates work out to other classes.

[image]

One way to do this is for the `Game` to pass references to its own properties as and when the `Player` needs them.

For example have `collision` take a `bots` parameter rather than the `Game

```
bool collision(const std::vector<Bot&> bots)  {
    // note pass objects by const ref is usu preferred in C++ to pass by value

   for (Bot bot: g.bots)
   ...
 }
```

(Note in a more sophisticated approach, it could pass interfaces, i.e. abstract base classes, onto itself).

If all else fails, you can go back to using a forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the easiest thing would be a forward declaration, and moving some code from the header file to the source file.

Like this

Player.h

```
#include "Bot.h"

class Game; // forward declaration

class Player {
    private:
    bool collision(Game g);
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Game.h"

bool Player::collision(Game g)  {

   for (Bot bot: g.bots)
   ...
}
```

The forward declaration tells the compiler that `Game` is the name of a class but nothing else. So the `Player::collision` method must be moved to the Player.cpp file where the full definition of Game is available.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do this since If A contains B, and B contains A, it would be infinite size.  Infact you can create two classes that store pointers to one another, by using the **forward declaration**, so that the two classes know of each other's existence

Answer (score 1):

Forward declaration is required - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration